# combining several participle of verb + miru

Tags: grammar, usage, verbs

I am practicing expressing "to try to do something", using the participle of verbs plus 見る.

If I understand correctly, a sentence like:

> このビールを飲んでみました。

means something like:

> I tried to drink this beer."

Now, using the same grammatical structure, I am trying to say:

> I will try to talk to my parents and decide whether I will buy it or not.

The first part would be: 私の両親と話してみます
and the second: これを買うかどうか決めて見ます。(not sure if that is right, this is just my best shot at it right now)

Now I try to combine them in one sentence, but the following sounds quite wrong in my beginner's ears:

> 私の両親と話して、これを買うかどうか決めて見ます。

What is the right way to say this?

Comment: I think you're overcomplicating this. これを買うかどうか決めます seems to fit better to what you're trying to say; no need for 〜みます. Also, you can omit 私の in the 1st sentence, but other than that it seems to be an appropriate translation on its own. But, because the conversation acts as a factor on whether or not you buy it, you don't need 〜みます at all when you combine the 2 sentences.
両親と話して、買うかどうか決めます is probably the most optimal solution, but granted it doesn't use 〜てみる at all.

Comment: Since this is exercise from a text book, I have to stick to the grammar form that I am exercising - thus, the use of 見ます :)
I am still so much a beginner, that it is hard to say if some grammar form is better than another in many cases, so I highly appreciate input like yours. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> このビールを飲んでみました。

I think it means 'I tried drinking this beer' (You drank it).
'I tried to drink this beer' would be 「このビールを飲もうとしました」(You may or may not have drunk it).

If I understand correctly,
'try doing' 「～してみる」
'try to do' 「～しようとする」
'will try to do' 「～しようと思う」「～したいと思う」(Literally 'I think I will ~' 'I think I want to ~')

> I will try to talk to my parents and decide whether I will buy it or not.

I think it will be 「両親と話して、これを買うかどうか決めようと思います or 決めたいと思います。」

「私の両親と話して、これを買うかどうか決めてみます。」 doesn't sound natural to me.